# OPENROWSET only accepting VARCHAR/NVARCHAR for a Date column in a CSV, not DATE (Synapse Serverless)

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, openrowset

A CSV file is being dumped into an Azure Datalake. When I try to make an `OPENROWSET` view in Synapse Serverless, the date column is only working as a `VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR`, not any sort of `DATE`.

Here's the CSV file with the offending column:

[image: The Date Column of the CSV file, if I download it.]

My Synapse Serverless `VIEW`/`SELECT` statements works, if I put the column as a `VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR`:

```
CREATE TestView AS

SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'Orders Forecast.csv'
 ,DATA_SOURCE = 'workday'
 ,FORMAT = 'CSV'
 ,PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
 ,HEADER_ROW = TRUE

) 

WITH (
     [Period] varchar(50)
    )
AS t
```

But then it's not easily usable as a date when querying the VIEW.

If I try to assign it as `DateTime2`, it errors:

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS

SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'Orders Forecast.csv'
, DATA_SOURCE = 'workday'
, FORMAT = 'CSV'
, PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
--, ROWSET_OPTIONS = '{"READ_OPTIONS":["ALLOW_INCONSISTENT_READS"]}'
, HEADER_ROW = TRUE

) 

WITH (
     [Period] datetime2
    )
```

> ERROR: Msg 13812, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for  the specified codepage) for row starting at byte offset 138, column 8
> (Period) in Orders Forecast.csv.

I've also tried going down to `PARSER_VERSION` 1.0, and doing the then-compatible `DATETIME`. And `DATE`. Same results.

Comment: Can I suggest you view the data in notepad, not excel, to see what the data really looks like

Comment: @Nick.Mc good call. In Notepad the data shows things like "12/2023".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the code below for getting it in `datetime` format.

When using ***openrowset**, you should explicitly specify the collation when declaring the column type inside the **WITH** clause.

```sql
    WITH (
        [C1] VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8
    )
```

Next, use the **TRY_PARSE** function.

```sql
SELECT TRY_PARSE(c1 AS datetime USING 'en-US') AS result
FROM cte;
```

Here is the initial data.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: @JayshankarGS thanks!  1.) The DB collation is Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8. Should I explicitly state that always on every varchar column?  2.) TRY_PARSE is neat. IT seems to be about 25% slower, but less janky.  I'm a little torn, would you recommend it over DATEFROMPARTS?

Comment: "For invalid arguments, DATEFROMPARTS will raise an error". TRY_PARSE will just return NULL. Which would you rather?

Answer (score 0):

I can wrap the whole thing in a CTE, then run a DATEFROMPARTS on it. This absolutely works. But, is there not a better way?

```
CREATE Test View AS

WITH CTE AS (

SELECT  * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'Orders Forecast.csv'
, DATA_SOURCE = 'workday'
, FORMAT = 'CSV'
, PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
--, ROWSET_OPTIONS = '{"READ_OPTIONS":["ALLOW_INCONSISTENT_READS"]}'
, HEADER_ROW = TRUE

) 

WITH (
     [Period] varchar(50)
    )
AS t

    )


SELECT

,DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(CTE.Period,4),LEFT(CTE.PERIOD,2),1) as PeriodFixed


FROM CTE

GO
```